# Problem in XML parser program

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am doing a simple XML parser program.I am running it in command prompt.The program (abc.java) compiles successfully.But it gives following error after running it:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin>java abc abc.xml
```

> [Fatal Error] abc.xml:1:8: The
>   processing instruction target matching
>   "[xX][mM][ lL]" is not allowed.
>   Parsing error, line 1, URI
>   file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin/abc.xml
>
> The processing instruction target
>   matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not
>   allowed.

What does it mean? Please help.

Here is my xml file if needed.(abc.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title> 
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author> 
  <year>2005</year> 
  <price>30.00</price> 
  </book>

  <book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title> 
  <author>J K. Rowling</author> 
  <year>2005</year> 
  <price>29.99</price> 
  </book>
  </bookstore>
```

Comment: Are there spaces before <?xml? Not sure, but this may be a problem

Comment: thanks yu_sha.It worked.Please post it as an answer.I'll mark it as best.You must get your credit.

Comment: It is illegal to have spaces before it.

Comment: Thanks stevendick.I didn't know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems like you have spaces in your xml file before 
xml tag

if so, remove them